# How to Put Categorized Parsed JSON Items inside an Array in Swift 4

Tags: json, swift

I have successfully parsed JSON data individually using Decodable.
What I need to do next is to put the same items into an Array. For instance, here's what I did to get the "dates" items:

```
struct Item : Decodable {
let date: String }
```

and retrieving it in a JSON parser function using:

```
let items = try JSONDecoder().decode([Item].self, from: data!)

for info in items {
        print(info.date) }
```

How do I put the said dates inside an Array?

(Note: There are many item categories inside the JSON data including: name, date, price, etc., I just need to get the "dates" item.)

What I tried so far is this:

```
var itemDate = [String]() // declare an Array

// Inside the JSON parser function:
self.itemDate.append(info.date)
let dateArrays = [self.itemDate]
print(dateArrays)
```

The result, however, shows up like this:

[image]

Comment: try like this once `let items = try JSONDecoder().decode(Item.self, from: data!)}` to parse

Comment: Hi @NeelBhasin, an error shows up: `Type 'TryViewController3.Item' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'` on `for info in items {`

Comment: What is your issue ? array of array ?

Comment: You have added it yourself `[self.itemDate]` remove that `[]` if you don't want array of array

Comment: Don't know... I just need to put the category "dates" into an Array.

Comment: Your code is correct except  `let dateArrays = [self.itemDate]` it should let `dateArrays = self.itemDate`

Comment: Try to avoid the forced unwrapping of `data` when you do `data!`, instead properly unwrap the `Optional`. You'll avoid possible hard-to-debug crashes down the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `map` function is one way you could go.

From your `items` array, you could just map the Structs to an array containing only dates like so:

```
let justTheDatesArray = items.map{$0.date}
```

Alternatively, you could do it when you decode:

```
let items = try JSONDecoder().decode([Item].self, from: data!).map{$0.date}
```

You can read more about `map`, `filter`, and `reduce` [here](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-guide-to-map-filter-reduce/)

Bonus:

If you want to pull actual `Date` objects out, you could use `DateFormatter`, like so:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "mm/DD/yyyy"
let dateObjectArray = justTheDatesArray.flatMap{formatter.date(from: $0)}
```

Comment: Thanks @Adrian, I will try it later. Will mark your answer as correct if it worked.

Comment: Hi @Adrian, the result shows up like this: `[2018-01-28 16:01:00 +0000, 2018-01-29 16:01:00 +0000, 2018-01-30 16:01:00 +0000, 2017-12-31 16:02:00 +0000, 2018-01-01 16:02:00 +0000, 2018-01-04 16:02:00 +0000, 2018-01-05 16:02:00 +0000]` I used the dateFormatter but result shows above. I did `print(dateObjectArray)`

Comment: When I only print the `items`, it shows this: `["1/29/2018", "1/30/2018", "1/31/2018", "2/1/2018", "2/2/2018", "2/5/2018", "2/6/2018"]`

Answer (score 0):

With `let dateArrays = [self.itemDate]`, you are declaring an array **inside** an array (hence the print call is `[[]]`. You can just simply use the variable `itemDate` directly (it is already an array of your `dates` item) or if you like, use

```
let dateArrays = self.itemDate
```

Without the square brackets, it is just an array, not an array of arrays.

Comment: Hi @paper1111, I tried it but it shows up like this: `["1/25/2018"]
["1/25/2018", "1/26/2018"]
["1/25/2018", "1/26/2018", "1/29/2018"]
["1/25/2018", "1/26/2018", "1/29/2018", "1/30/2018"]`

Comment: I would need for the result to show as: `"1/25/2018", "1/26/2018", "1/29/2018", "1/30/2018", "1/31/2018", "2/1/2018", "2/2/2018", "2/5/2018", "2/6/2018"` without the [], is that possible?